# Numpy combine two MaskedArrays with OR operation

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, combinations

I have two MaskedArray objects, with the same length:

```
>> grades_passed
   [90 -- 88 62 -- 100]
>> grades_not_passed
  [-- 54 -- -- 34 --]
```

And I'm trying to combine them to get:

```
[90 54 88 62 34 100]
```

I tried some manipulations like:

```
total_final = grades_passed + grades_not_passed
```

or

```
total_final = ma.mask_or(grades_passed, grades_not_passed)
total_final = ma.concatenate(grades_passed, grades_not_passed)
```

But none of them do the trick

Comment: In your example the masks are `not` of each other.  Is that always the case?

Comment: `a.filled(0) + b.filled(0)` might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works, as long as there is no overlap of the two masks:

```
grades = grades_passed.filled(1) * grades_not_passed.filled(1)
```

The parameter `1` temporarily sets the `fill_value` of the two variables, so masked values take on `1` as value to be filled.

Comment: Or simply `np.array(grades_passed.filled(1) * grades_not_passed.filled(1))`

Comment: Thanks @yatu. I adapted the answer to match your proposal.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the arrays to lists and create dictionaries with index values (this assumes that the two arrays won't have a value in the same index position).  Then you can combine those and output the result as a masked array or list:

```
def combine_grades(passed, failed):
    # Put index:value for each list into a dictionary
    pass_dict = {list(passed).index(i):i for i in list(passed) if i != '--'}
    fail_dict = {list(failed).index(i):i for i in list(failed) if i != '--'}

    # Combine those dictionaries
    full_dict = {**pass_dict, **fail_dict}

    # Return a masked array (if that's what you want. Otherwise, just return the list)
    return ma.array([full_dict[i] for  i in sorted(full_dict)])
```

Then call:

```
combine_grades(grades_passed, grades_not_passed)
```

Output:

```
masked_array(data=[ 90,  54,  88,  62,  34, 100],
             mask=False,
       fill_value=999999)
```